# Question on Evaluating Inverse Trigonometric Expression $(\sin^{-1}a)^2-(\cos^{-1}b)^2+(\sec^{-1}c)^2-(\csc^{-1}d)^2$

Tags: trigonometry

If
$$(\sin^{-1}a)^2+(\cos^{-1}b)^2+(\sec^{-1}c)^2+(\csc^{-1}d)^2=\frac {5\pi^2}2$$

Then find the value of
$$(\sin^{-1}a)^2-(\cos^{-1}b)^2+(\sec^{-1}c)^2-(\csc^{-1}d)^2$$

---

It would have been so much easier if $a=b=c=d=\theta $. But, no. I have tried the basic manipulations but I have no progress. Could anyone just give me the direction in which I have to proceed?

Comment: Off hand I believe it is impossible.  The given is of the form $X+Y=\frac{7\pi^2}{2}$ and you are to find $X-Y$.

Comment: I am so sorry. The value was $\frac {5\pi^2}{2} $

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$(\sin^{-1}a)^2+(\cos^{-1}b)^2+(\sec^{-1}c)^2+(\csc^{-1}d)^2=\frac {5\pi^2}2$$

is true only if

$$(\sin^{-1}a)^2=\frac{\pi^2}{4},\>\>\>(\cos^{-1}b)^2=\pi^2,\>\>\>
(\sec^{-1}c)^2=\pi^2,\>\>\>(\csc^{-1}d)^2=\frac{\pi^2}4$$

due to their respective range limits. Thus, the value is

$$(\sin^{-1}a)^2-(\cos^{-1}b)^2+(\sec^{-1}c)^2-(\csc^{-1}d)^2$$
$$=\frac{\pi^2}{4}-\pi^2+\pi^2-\frac{\pi^2}{4}=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Use  principal values from https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions

the left side $$\le2(\pi)^2+2(\pi/2)^2$$

So, the equality occurs if $a=c=\pm1$ and $b=c=0$